# Cookies not seeming to be passed in to fetch call in Next.js 14 server component

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I can't find a solution for this anywhere, and feel like I'm losing my mind.

I have the following server component:

```
export default async function Page() {

    const research = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/research/get-all", {
        credentials: "include"
    })

    const json = await research.json()

    console.log(json)

    return (
        <Suspense fallback={ <Loading /> }>
            <DashboardTableHeader />   
        </Suspense>
    )
}
```

It sends a network request to my backend, including a cookie which I can visibly see in my browser application tab.

However, my server isn't receiving the cookie in the request like it should be.

If I've understood it right, the server component is calling the function before it reaches the browser, and therefore it can never know the cookie before rendering.

However if I go to middleware.ts and console log req.cookies like so:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {

    console.log(req.cookies)

}
```

Then the cookie shows in my console absolutely fine.

So somewhere, I'm not doing something right. The documentation is no help at all, and creating a server action or route handler makes no sense.

Does anyone have any advice about what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: it might be related to caching in `fetch`.  can you console.log() somehting in your api route to see if the request hits the endpoint